# Recover stdin from eof in C

Tags: c, exception, stdin, eof

I am using the C code below to read user input from a terminal. If the user inputs EOF, e.g. by pressing ^C, stdin is closed and subsequent attempts to read from it, e.g. via getchar() or scanf(), will cause an exception.

Is there anything I can do in C to "recover" my program, in the sense that if some user accidently inputs EOF, this will be ignored, so I can read from stdin again?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int res_getchar=getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking?

Comment: After you die can someone get you back to life? Same happens with `stdin`, if you send `eof` then you kill it.

Comment: I am looking for transanimation :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ungetc()` to push back a character can clear the EOF indicator for a stream.

> C99 §7.19.7.11 The `ungetc` function
>
> ```
>  int ungetc(int c, FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> **A successful call to the `ungetc` function clears the end-of-file indicator for the stream.** The value of the file position indicator for the stream after reading or discarding all pushed-back characters shall be the same as it was before the characters were pushed back.

Comment: Interesting; but it doesn't change the fact that EOF is coming.

Comment: When I use `ungetc(EOF,stdin);` on my system in the above code, it returns EOF, that is, it fails...

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill That depends on what OP is looking for, this is a way to recover from EOF.

Comment: @lee77 That's because you can't push back an `EOF`, you need to push back a real character.

Comment: Thanks Yu Hao, this actually works on my system! So this works on every C99-compliant system, right?

Comment: @lee77 I quoted the C99 standard, but `ungetc` is available in C89 as well.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the situation correctly - you're reading from a terminal via `stdin`, the user types <kbd>^D</kbd>, you want to discard that and ask again for input - you have two options, one more portable (and quite simple) but less likely to work, and one less portable (and considerably more programming) but certain to work.

- The [`clearerr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clearerr) function is standard C, and is documented to clear both the sticky error and sticky EOF flags on a `FILE` object; if your problem is that the C library isn't bothering to call [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) again once it's indicated EOF once, this may help.

  If this solves your immediate problem, make sure that if you get some number of EOFs in a row (four to ten, say) you give up and quit, because if `stdin` is *not* a terminal, or if the terminal has genuinely been closed down, that EOF condition is never going to go away, and you don't want your program to get stuck in an infinite loop when that happens.
- On POSIX-compliant systems only (i.e. "not Windows"), you can use [`cfmakeraw`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/cfmakeraw) to disable the input preprocessing that turns <kbd>^D</kbd> into an EOF indication.

  Doing this means you also have to handle a *whole lot* of other stuff yourself; you may instead want to use a third-party library that handles it for you, e.g. [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) (GPL) or [editline](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/) (BSD).  If your program is any sort of nontrivial interactive command interpreter, using one of these libraries is *strongly encouraged*, as it will provide a much nicer user experience.

Comment: Yes, the situation is like that, it's a terminal. Thanks for the hint about the genuinely closed terminal.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer, too, but it seems that isn't possible... I tossed a coin...

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. You read EOF when the OS has closed stdin.

I am sure there are Platform-dependent ways to preserve some info that would let you reconstruct stdin after it was closed -- ie, open a new stream connected to the keyboard and assign it to stdin -- but there's definitely no portable way.

Comment: Looking at other answers, "In a word, no" seems incorrect. Or at least not useful.