# Continuting input after end of file

Tags: c++

Is there any way that I can continue input after end of file or invalid input. The `record` function will throw an exception if a certain data member is not recorded. I want to catch the exception and use another function `rerecord` to enter the information. The program will catch the exception and print the output but it won't do the last part.

```
int main()
{
    info person;
    try {
        person.record(std::cin);
    }
    catch(std::domain_error e) {
        std::cout << "Re-enter person info" << std::endl;
        person.rerecord(std::cin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what ctrl-d means in your program?

Comment: How about using `clear(eofbit)` When you found the EOF ie, reset the stream

Comment: Also If you don't want to terminate the input stream, just don't press Ctrl+D!

Comment: I should have been more clear. It's not just ctrl-D. The exception will be caught when input fails. But will not execute the last line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover stdin from eof in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744423/recover-stdin-from-eof-in-c)

Comment: @RahulTripathi. Do you mean `std::cin.clear()`? Or do I negate `eofbit`. `~eofbit`.

Answer (score 0):

I think some input operation failed in `person.record(std::cin);` and `cin` is in a bad state.
In this case
"[How do I flush the cin buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer)" should help.
Especially, note the **call to `ignore(...)`** to get ride of the bad input!

Running code for demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    int i;

    std::cout << "Input: ";

    std::cin >> i;

    std::cout << "Received: " << i << "\nInput next:";

    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    std::cin >> i;

    std::cout << "Received: " << i << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I hit Ctrl-D at the first input, std::cin.clear() does not remove EOF.  If I repeat `std::cin.clear()` after ignore, EOF is actually removed from the flags, but cin doesn't input anything anymore.  (g++ (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110)