# How to ask for infinite user inputs in C?

Tags: c, arrays, input, eof

I want to create an infinite loop such that I'm able to ask the user for up to 2 inputs, and store them into an array (a) and then print these array values. I want it then to restart, and repeat this process of asking and repeating. With my current code, once I enter values and declare End of Function (EOF), the console infinitely prints out these values rather than restarting and asking for new values.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    
int a[2];
int i = 0;
while (1 < 2) {

    while(scanf("%d", &a[i]) != EOF) {
        i++;
        //i == number of inputs (max is 2)
    }
    
    
    int j = 0;
    
    while(j < i) {
    
        printf("%d ", a[j]);
        j++;
        
    }

 
}           
            
return 0;

}
```

My hypothesis is that the scanf("%d", &a[i]) value has not reset after being declared as being EOF but I'm not entirely sure on how to do that.

Comment: `EOF` is end of *file*, and it effectively marks the input stream `stdin` (where `scanf` reads from) as invalid and you can't continue to read from it. You need to come up with another way of detecting "end of *input*" (for example by just stop reading after you have read your two values).

Comment: "//i == number of inputs (max is 2)" Your code doesn't seem to care about that maximum.

Comment: So the algorithm is `do_forever(input 2 numbers; print these numbers)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover stdin from eof in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744423/recover-stdin-from-eof-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

You have undefined behavior because of accessing out of bound.
You need to reset the `i` on each iteration or even better limit the scope of `i` to each iteration.

```
int i = 0;

while (1) {
    i = 0; // reset i

    while(scanf("%d", &a[i]) == 1 && i < 2) {
        i++;
        //i == number of inputs (max is 2)
    }
    ...   
}
```

Comment: `while (1 < 2)`? Why not `while (1)`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't know. What OP is thinking :D