# Problem with MacBook EOF in Xcode and Terminal

Tags: c, xcode, macos, terminal, eof

Okay so im currently learning c and my problem is that my teacher wants us to use a code he sent us it works on windows but it doesn't work on Mac, he can't seem to find the problem, im using a MacBook with the M1 chip, the problem on Mac Is when I use Crtl + D to signal EOF after my input in editFileContents it will edit the file but it will keep looping this in the compiler over and over again:

```
Menu:
1. Display file
2. Edit file
3. Create new file
4. Exit
Choice: Enter the new text (end with Ctrl+D in Unix or Ctrl+Z in Windows):
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH 256
#define MAX_TEXT_LENGTH 1024

void deleteFile(char *filename){
    if (remove(filename) == 0) {
        printf("File %s deleted:\n", filename);
    } else {
        perror("Could not delete the file");
    }
}

void displayFileContents(char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open the file '%s'\n", filename);
        return;
    }

    char line[MAX_TEXT_LENGTH];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    fclose(file);
}

void editFileContents(char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "a+");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open the file '%s'\n", filename);
        return;
    }

    char newContents[MAX_TEXT_LENGTH];
    printf("Enter the new text (end with Ctrl+D in Unix or Ctrl+Z in Windows):\n");

    while (fgets(newContents, sizeof(newContents), stdin) != NULL) {
        size_t len = strlen(newContents);
        if (len > 0 && newContents[len - 1] == '\n') {
            newContents[len - 1] = '\0';
        }
        fprintf(file, "%s\n", newContents);
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int createNewFile(char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file != NULL) {
        printf("File already exists\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 0; // out of createFile
     }
    else {
        FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (file == NULL) {
            printf("Could not create the file '%s'\n", filename);
            return 1; // out of createFile
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    editFileContents(filename);
    return 2;
}

int main() {
    char filename[MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH];
    printf("Enter the filename to work on\n");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    int choice;

    while (1){
        printf("\nMenu:\n");
        printf("1. Display file\n");
        printf("2. Edit file\n");
        printf("3. Create new file\n");
        printf("4. Exit\n");
        printf("Choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                displayFileContents(filename);
                break;
            case 2:
                editFileContents(filename);
                break;
            case 3:
                createNewFile(filename);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Exiting...\n");
                return 0;  // out of main()
            default:
                printf("Invalid choice. Try again.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

So have been stuck with this problem for a few days I tried everything, that I can think of including chatGPT

I did insure I was editing the right file

I did try my best at troubleshooting the problem but can't seem to find it.

I tried changing from Xcode to the Terminal which didn't change anything.

Comment: I think you are trying to read past end-of-file, making this question a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744423/recover-stdin-from-eof-in-c).

Comment: Yoy did not initialize `choice` and you did not test the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &choice);` is the same as `fscanf(stdin, "%d", &choice);`. Notice the `stdin`? Also remember you typed <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> when editing the text... putting `stdin` in "End-Of-File" condition. Hmmm... smells fishy... maybe `clearerr(stdin);` right after detetcting `EOF` helps???

Answer (score 1):

Your program exits the `while` loop only when `choice` is 4. But, when the program receives an end-of-file indication, nothing in your program sets `choice` to 4.

When an end-of-file indication is encountered before `scanf` completes any conversions of input items, `scanf("%d", &choice)` returns the value of the macro `EOF`, and it does not change the value stored in `choice`. To detect this, you must test the return value of `scanf`. If it is not 1, indicating that one conversion of an input item was completed, then `scanf("%d", choice)` did not store a value in `choice`.